# Spring Cloud DataFlow and MySQL doesn't show the START_TIME and END_TIME of the Task

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I'm working on `Spring batch and SCDF` example. In this example I am reading `CSV` file and loading all the data to `MySQL`. I was able to successfully load the data into MySQL DB, but but UI doesn't show me `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`, even db doesn't holds any records.

I've uploaded my code here: https://github.com/JavaNeed/spring-cloud-dataflow-example1.git

spring-cloud-data-flow-server

SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.java

```
@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudDataFlowServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.cloud.dataflow.features.streams-enabled=false
#spring.cloud.dataflow.rdbms.initialize.enable=false
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-data-flow-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-data-flow-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version>2.4.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

JobConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(){
        FlatFileItemReader<Customer> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.csv"));

        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"id", "firstName", "lastName", "birthdate"});

        DefaultLineMapper<Customer> customerLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        customerLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        customerLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new CustomerFieldSetMapper());
        customerLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

        reader.setLineMapper(customerLineMapper);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter(){
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :birthdate)");
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer> chunk(10)
                .reader(customerItemReader())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }   
}
```

application.properties

```
# MYSQL DB Details
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.schema=org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql 


spring.batch.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
#spring.batch.schema=classpath:schema-mysql.sql
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a brief review of [`databaseOutput`](https://github.com/JavaNeed/spring-cloud-dataflow-example1/tree/master/databaseOutput/) application, it appears you aren't using Spring Cloud Task.

Today, SCDF recognizes, resolves, and automates the orchestration of Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Task applications natively. While other workloads (including [polyglot](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/polyglot/)) are possible, only these two types of applications are treated with more care and automation.

In your case, in particular, even if your batch-job successfully did its thing, the transaction boundary is only governed if the batch-job application is wrapped as a Spring Cloud Task application, which is the reason why you don't see transactions recorded in SCDF's database. Likewise, the UI/Shell/API won't show such details either.

I would recommend reviewing the [batch developer guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/) in entirety. Perhaps repeat the guide as-is first to get a feel of how things come together. Once when you get to see them in action (esp. `spring-cloud-task` boundaries), you will then be able to retrofit your app to comply with the foundational-level expectations.